# How to update particular column dynamically

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm using the following table

```
book_Catalog contains
  book name,
  book_id,
  book_title,
  created_by(contains the detail which user created this entry),      
  updated_by(contains the detail which user updates this entry)
  created_by column uses the system date
```

Please give an idea
what query should be used to fill the update_by column??

Thanks in advance,

Ashmitha

Comment: where's the code formatting?

Comment: Have you just done a class that covered triggers, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_BOOK_CATALOG_UPDATED_BY
    (pin_BOOK_ID BOOK_CATALOG.UPDATED_BY%TYPE)
IS
BEGIN
  UPDATE BOOK_CATALOG
    SET UPDATED_BY = UID
    WHERE BOOK_ID = pin_BOOK_ID;
END UPDATE_BOOK_CATALOG_UPDATED_BY;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER to do this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER My_Trigger
AFTER INSERT 
ON TABLE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
END;/
```